# Run java software from OpenVMS

Tags: java, com, openvms

I have a .com file that starts a java software from OpenVMS. Now I need to add the following option to the .com script:

set process/parse=extended

But it doesn't work!

`set process/parse_style=extended`

`java myjavafile`

Returns a:

%SKP-DATA: (Records not beginning with "$" ignored)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Every line that's intended as a DCL command should start with a $:

> $ set process/parse_style=extended
>
> $ java myjavafile